# JSON to java object using gson for multiple records

Tags: java, json

```
I have my json file and corresponding java bean classes.
JSON file has multiple records,So i have LIST of objects,where i am facing the problem.LIST is not being populated. 
JSON file:
{"RequestServices":
{`enter code here`
"RequestService":
[
{
"orderNumber":456,
"organizationId":123,
"headerId":3446
}
]
}
}
JAVA CLASSES:
public class RequestServices {
    private List<RequestService> requestServices=new ArrayList<RequestService>();//array of objects     
//default getter,setter of List<RequestService>
}
-----
public class RequestService {   
    private String orderNumber;
    private String organizationId;
    private String headerId;
    /* setters and getters */}
-----
Main.class
public class JSONBind {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new fileReader("c:\\JSON1.json"));
        //convert the json string back to object
        RequestServices obj = gson.fromJson(br, RequestServices.class);
```

System.out.println(obj.getRequestServices().get(0).getOrderNumber());//Getting error
        }}}
    When i try to print list of objects(i.eREquestService),Its giving IndexOutofBound
    Thanks in advance, Waitin for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed in your json you have the following hierarchy

```
RequestServices -> RequestService[]
```

but in your Pojos you have `RequestServices -> requestServices` try to rename your pojo or your json to match the properties to `requestServices`

Or you can map the field in your POJO with the annotation `@SerializedName("requestServices")`

For a full documentation you can check the site: [Gson Doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed the variable names as exactly to json file, Its working fine now,

Comment: But one mre question., Can we map json values to java object variable name in GSON?

Comment: Glad to help you! As it solved the problem, can you please, accept the answer? about your question i didn't understand it, could you explain?

Comment: Eg: attribute name of JSON is 'OrderNumber', But in my POJO class , Instead ordernumber, i have 'salesNumber' as attribute name. Now how can we map that OrderNumber from JSON to salesNumber of POJO class?

Comment: Eg: attribute name of JSON is 'OrderNumber', But in my POJO class , Instead ordernumber, i have 'salesNumber' as attribute name. Now how can we map that OrderNumber from JSON to salesNumber of POJO class?

Comment: @user1570345, yeah its possible, i edited my answer!